# Is there a proper name for those 'shifted moments'?

Tags: pr.probability, terminology, moments

Suppose that we have a random variable $X$, $i \in \mathbb N$, and a scalar $t$. Is there a proper name for these integrals, that I for the moment call 'shifted moments' ?

$$I_{i}^{t} = \mathbb{E}\left(X^i e^{tX}\right)$$

I use the name 'shifted moments' as they are derivatives of the moment generating function, but not in $t = 0$.

How would you call them ?

Comment: $I_0^t$ is called the cumulant generating function; wouldn't you then just call $I_i^t$ the $i$-th derivative of this function? (up to a factor $t^i$)

Comment: I think $I_0^t$ is the moment generating function. It's log is the cumulant generating function.

Comment: certainly, cumulant $\mapsto$ moment, my mistake.

Comment: Yes of course, these are derivatives of the moment generating function. But i watned to found a better name. If there is not, i'll take it. (Btw, i have the same issue with cumulant generating function).

Answer (score 2):

These are moments of what is often called the [exponentially tilted distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_tilting).